# What does it exactly mean if something "Requires Qt4"?

Tags: software-installation, qt, cmake

I need to get [this program to work](http://www.purinchu.net/software/elflibviewer.php). As usual with linux software, it requires that I compile it myself without any real instructions. Fine, I tried to run cmake on it.

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~/Downloads/elflibviewer-0.9$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jakub/libview; make && make install
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1316 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jakub/Downloads/elflibviewer-0.9/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

As I said, it requires Qt, but the thing is I think I have Qt:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~/$ apt --installed list | grep qt

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

libqt4-dbus/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt4-designer/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt4-gui/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed]
libqt4-opengl/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt4-script/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt4-svg/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt4-xml/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqtcore4/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqtdbus4/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqtgui4/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qt-at-spi/stable,now 0.3.1-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qtchooser/stable,now 47-gd2b7997-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qtcore4-l10n/stable,now 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 all [installed,automatic]
```

In the `CMakeList.txt` it says:

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(elflibviewer_SRCS
    MainWindowImpl.cpp
    main.cpp
    )

qt4_wrap_cpp(elflibviewer_MOCS MainWindowImpl.h)
qt4_wrap_ui(elflibviewer_UIS elflibviewer.ui)
qt4_add_resources(elflibviewer_RCS resources.qrc)
```

I can see both `core` and `gui` in the list of installed packages so what's exactly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have the runtime shared library packages installed.  That is fine if all you want to do is RUN pre-compiled programs that depend on those libs.

If you want to compile programs that depend on those libs, you need to install the various qt4 `-dev` packages - these contain the header files etc needed to compile programs using those libs.  You probably also need to install the `qt4-qmake` package.

Comment: Thanks, it was this command specifically: `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`.